# How to integrate Jbehave and TestNG?

Tags: java, testng, bdd, jbehave

I googled and found most of scripts were written in Jbehave with junit. But I'm trying to integrate Jbehave with testNG framework. And the following were I tried so far.

Feature file:

```
Scenario: Check the google search engine
Given : Open the google home page www.google.com
When : Enter test automation in search box
Then : Proper result should be displayed in results page
```

Test step class file:

```
public class GoogleSearchEngine_Steps {

    public static WebDriver driver;

    @Given("Open the google home page $url")
    public static void openUrl(String url) throws Exception {
        try {

            driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            driver.get(url);

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @When("Enter $searchKeyword in search box")
    public static void searchKeyword(String searchKeyword) throws Exception {
        try {

            driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='gs_htif0']")).sendKeys(searchKeyword);
            driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='tsf']/input[1]")).click();

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Then("Proper result should be displayed in results page")
    public static void result() throws Exception {
        try {

            driver.quit();

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

But I have stuck to create a test runner class file using TestNg. I'm not sure How to start.

Can somebody help me to create a test runner class file which will execute the above code.

Answer (score 1):

Did you check http://jbehave.org/reference/stable/running-stories.html? It has code sample for running jbehave stories.

Comment: Link only answers usually get flagged and in some cases removed. It'll be better if you write the solution here and write the link as reference.